# How to display “241.14999999999998” as “241.15” in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rounding

Actually I am designing a conversion calculator which will convert from Kilometer to meter, Celsius to Fahrenheit etc.

In that I am getting `241.14999999999998` as a converted form of a value but I want to see it as `241.15`.

So what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
241.14999999999998.toFixed(2);
```

**Note:**

> A string representing the given number using fixed-point notation.

is what is returned. So, you can use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) if you want to manipulate it.

**Output**

```
241.15
```

**Live Example**

```js
console.log(241.14999999999998.toFixed(2));
```

**Reading Material**

[`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: .toFixed returns a string not a number however.

Comment: @SudhirOjha yes, I've mentioned that.

Answer (score 3):

Use JavaScript `toFixed()` Method:

```
var num = 13.3714;
var n = num.toFixed(2);
console.log(n)
```

> Result: 13.37

Answer (score 0):

```js
y = Math.round(241.14999999999998 * 100) / 100;
console.log(y);
```